# Removing the session

Tags: php, forms, session

I am having a problem that when ever once a user enter the email  to register then the code shows the output that email has been registered but it does not destroy the session the same message keep on displaying even after the other user loged in and logged out. I think there is something missing in the AND.
Thank you.

```
<?php
     if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) AND !isset($_SESSION['ID'])){
     ?>
     <div class="alert alert-success">
         The email has been registered. <strong>Welcome to Secret diary</strong>. Please login.
     </div>

    <?php
        session_destroy(); };
?>
```

This is another code.

```
<?php

include 'dbh.php';
session_start();
$first=$_POST['fname'];
$last=$_POST['lname'];
$gender=$_POST['optradio'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];
$conf=$_POST['conpass'];
$first5=substr(md5($pass), 0,5);
$sqli="SELECT * FROM user_reg WHERE email='$email'";

$result1=mysqli_query($conect,$sqli);

if (!$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

$sql="INSERT INTO user_reg (fname,lname,gender,email,password)         VALUES('$first','$last','$gender','$email','$encry')";
$result=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);

}else{

$_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];

};


header("Location:index.html");
$last5=substr(md5($pass), 15,5);
$encry=$first5.$last5;
         ?>
```

Comment: did you start the session?

Comment: btw, your conditional statement doesn't make any sense. You want to destroy something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to unset values from the session

`<?php 
   unset($_SESSION['email']);
   unset($_SESSION['ID']); 
 ?>`